# Apache2 new VirtualHost entry can not find server - DNS issue?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using `Apache2` on `Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS` server. Server is my company (work) server and has a public IP, moreover, it hosts about 5 different pages which are available worldwide, I mean, on the Internet, so being at home I can easily access them.

Recently, I was told to create another website (a new one) on that server that should also be accessible through the Internet.

This is what I did:

1. Created the page in `/home/mazix/test` directory
2. `chmod 755 /home/mazix/test`
3. Created a new `availble site` file (called `testorg`) in `/etc/apache2/sites/available`:

   ```
       ServerName testsite.org
       ServerAlias www.testsite.org
       DocumentRoot /home/mazix/test
       WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mazix/test/wsgi.py

       <Directory />
               Options FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride None
       </Directory>

       <Directory /home/mazix/test>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
               AllowOverride All
               Order allow,deny
               allow from all
       </Directory>

       ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
       <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
               AllowOverride None
               Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
       </Directory>

       ErrorLog /home/mazix/test/logs/error.log

       # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
       # alert, emerg.
       LogLevel warn

       CustomLog /home/mazix/test/access.log combined

   Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
   <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
   </Directory>
   ```
4. Did: `sudo a2ensite testorg`, and then `sudo service apache2 reload`

However, when I try to access the page from my home computer by typing in a browser `www.testsite.org` it shows the message thaqt the browser could not find the server ..

I don't really know what's going on. I thought that maybe it's the DNS issue? I checked the `/etc/hosts` file but there were no entries for remaining pages that are hosted by this server (however, they are still available on the Internet). I don't know if the server runs the DNS (problably not, but I have the root access, if you please tell me how to check it, I will do this).

My question is that: should I do something more to make the page available on the Internet? Should I add some DNS enteries? If so, how and where?

Some Apache info:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   May 28 2015 23:53:47
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.3.12
Compiled using: APR 1.4.6, APR-Util 1.3.12
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Result of `apache2 -S`:

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
         port 443 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
         port 443 namevhost work.abc.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/redmine:29)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server abc.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost abc.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost hewitt.se (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/steve:1)
         port 80 namevhost afg.uni.city.se (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/afg:1)
         port 80 namevhost wert.oop.net.se (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wert:1)
         port 80 namevhost test.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test:1)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Did you create a DS entry for the new system ? Most browsers provide a link to a more detailed error message - what exactly is this ? Show us the output of `apache2 -S`

Comment: What do you mean by creating a DS entry? You mean DNS? I did only what I wrote in my post, I'm not even sure if there's a DNS running on this specific company server. How can I create the DS entry you mentioned about?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a DNS record www.testsite.org in the public DNS pointing (directly or indirectly) to your server's IP address in order to make your server reachable from the Internet by the name www.testsite.org.
2. You can check whether such a DNS record exists and points to the correct server using the Linux host(1) command, eg. "host www.testsite.org".
3. If the DNS record does not exist, or points to the wrong server, it must be added or corrected in the DNS zone to which it belongs, ie. testsite.org.
4. In order to achieve that, contact the person responsible for the administration of that DNS zone and ask her to add or change the entry, giving her the IP address of your server.
5. If you don't know who is responsible for that DNS zone you may look it up using the whois(1) command, eg. "whois testsite.org", but in that case you probably shouldn't be using that server name anyway.

Comment: Thank you, your answer explained a lot to me. However, I just wondering - is it possible to create `test` as the subdomain of `abc.org`? I mean, there is `work.abc.org`, so I could have `test.abc.org`, right? Do I need a DNS record for this too?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create a subdomain test.abc.org of an existing domain abc.org (which may but needn't be a separate zone.) You can also create a host name test.abc.org (which is not the same as a subdomain.) And yes, all of these require appropriate DNS records to be added to the zone abc.org so you need the cooperation of that zone's administrator.